# Face API DetectAsync Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, face-api

I wanted to create a simple program to detect faces using Microsoft Azure Face API and Visual Studio 2015. Following the guide from (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37893.c-face-detection-and-recognition-with-azure-face-api.aspx), whenever my program calls UploadAndDetectFaces:

```
private async Task<Face[]> UploadAndDetectFaces(string imageFilePath)
{
    try
    {
        using (Stream imageFileStream = File.OpenRead(imageFilePath))
        {
            var faces = await faceServiceClient.DetectAsync(imageFileStream,
                true,
                 true,
                 new FaceAttributeType[] 
                 {
                     FaceAttributeType.Gender,
                     FaceAttributeType.Age,
                     FaceAttributeType.Emotion
                 });
            return faces.ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return new Face[0];
    }
}
```

I also declared the keys to the endpoint:

```
private readonly IFaceServiceClient faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceClient("MY_KEY_HERE");
```

an error returns:

> "Exception of type 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceAPIException' was thrown."

Does anyone know what's wrong or any changes required to prevent the error?

Comment: What is the full ErrorMessage & ErrorCode (you may need to catch FaceAPIException or cast the Exception).

Comment: You may also need to specify the actual endpoint that you were given when you got your key - the default may not be correct (_new FaceServiceClient("MY_KEY_HERE", "ACTUAL ENDPOINT HERE");_). See this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/tutorials/faceapiincsharptutorial). Another reason may be the image is too big. As I said check the ErrorMessage & ErrorCode of the exception - they give more detail.

Comment: @PaulF Thank you! I used (new FaceServiceClient("MY_KEY_HERE", "ACTUAL ENDPOINT HERE");) and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the key and endpoint declaration to:

```
private readonly IFaceServiceClient faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceClient("MY_KEY_HERE", "ACTUAL_ENDPOINT_HERE");
```