# FaceAPIException: while using the method DetectAsync

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I'm trying to use the DetectAsync method present in faceServiceClient.

```
using (Stream imageFileStream = webClient.OpenRead(imageFilePath))
{
      var faces = await faceServiceClient.DetectAsync(imageFileStream, returnFaceLandmarks: true, returnFaceAttributes: requiredFaceAttributes);
      var faceAttributes = faces.Select(face => face.FaceAttributes);
      string result = "trying no error";
      faceAttributes.ToList().ForEach(f =>
                     result += $"Age: {f.Age.ToString()} Years  Gender: {f.Gender}  Smile: {f.Smile.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}"
                  );
      return result;
}
```

and the exception is raised at the DetectAsync method

> Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceAPIException: Exception of type
>   ‘Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceAPIException’ was thrown. at
>   Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceServiceClient.d__672.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceServiceClient.d__29.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult() at
>   BotFace_Application.Utility.d__1.MoveNext()

Comment: Any exception message?

Comment: Exception of type ‘Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceAPIException’ was thrown.

Comment: no more details? Can you add your `faceServiceClient` declaration (edit the keys)?

Comment: private static readonly IFaceServiceClient faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apikey"]);

Comment: Looks like you got the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885650/face-api-detectasync-error
Just add the endpoitn