# Microsoft ProjectOxford Face API Error: System.UriFormatException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I was following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/howtoidentifyfacesinimage) for using the Microsoft Face API to identify faces in an image in Visual Studio when I got the following error printed in the Console:

> Error adding Person to Group Exception of type 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceAPIException' was thrown.

The exception is printed when the following function to add a person to an existing person group is called:

```
public async void AddPersonToGroup(string personGroupId, string name, string pathImage){
    try{
        await faceServiceClient.GetPersonGroupAsync(personGroupId);
        CreatePersonResult person = await faceServiceClient.CreatePersonAsync(personGroupId, name);

        foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(pathImage, "*.jpg")) {
            using (Stream s = File.OpenRead(imgPath)) {
                await faceServiceClient.AddPersonFaceAsync(personGroupId, person.PersonId, s);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex){
        //Below is where the error was printed.
        Console.WriteLine("Error adding Person to Group " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This is how I am calling `AddPersonToGroup` in the main method:

```
new Program().AddPersonToGroup("actor", "Tom Cruise", @"C:\Users\ishaa\Documents\Face_Pictures\Tom_Cruise\");
```

---

I tried searching up this error in Google and came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885650/face-api-detectasync-error), but that answer did not work for me. *(Their answer was to pass in the subscription key and endpoint for the `FaceServiceClient` constructor.)*

**Would anyone be able to provide any insight into why this error is occurring?** I have been unable to figure out what is causing it, but I believe it may have to do with
`await faceServiceClient.GetPersonGroupAsync(personGroupId);`. I also read that it may be due to the Cognitive Services pricing plan I have chosen. However, the free one which I am using allows for 20 transactions per minute and I am only trying to add 9 pictures for 3 different people.

Comment: Check to see if what you are trying to create already exists

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Nikosi. This is my first time using Microsoft Azure. By any chance, would you know how I can view the existing Person Groups in the Azure Portal? I have created a resource called Facial Recognition which I am using to get the keys. Is there a section where I can view that information because `Activity log` does not seem to contain it?

Comment: to help you, we need to know what kind of exception is thrown. Can you have a look when you catch the exception and get more details? Put a breakpoint and look at your `ex` object

Comment: @NicolasR thanks for the help on the other problem. I was able to get this to work by making some changes to the function. I also realized that it may have been possible that I was making too many calls, but now I finally understand how to use each of the functions effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to the problem by using the new function below which creates a Person Group, adds people to it, and enters images:

```
public async void AddPersonToGroup(string personGroupId, string name, string pathImage){
    //Create a Person Group called actors.
    await faceServiceClient.CreatePersonGroupAsync("actors, "Famous Actors");

    //Create a person and assign them to a Person Group called "actors"
    CreatePersonResult friend1 = await faceServiceClient.CreatePersonAsync("actors", "Tom Cruise");

    //Get the directory with all the images of the person.
    const string friend1ImageDir = @"C:\Users\ishaa\Documents\Face_Recognition_Pictures\Tom_Cruise\";
    foreach (string imagePath in Directory.GetFiles(friend1ImageDir, "*.jpg")){
        using (Stream s = File.OpenRead(imagePath)){
           try{
               //Add the faces for the person.
               await faceServiceClient.AddPersonFaceAsync("actors", friend1.PersonId, s);
           } catch (Exception e){
               Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

The following code above has worked for me in creating the Person Group, creating the People, and adding images for the people. I believe that there may be two causes of the initial error:

1. **`await faceServiceClient.GetPersonGroupAsync(personGroupId);`** could have been a possible issue. Now that I am not using it the code works with `faceServiceClient.CreatePersonGroupAsync`.
2. **Too many calls per minute**. I am currently using the free plan with 20 transactions per minute. What I did not realize was that each time I ran the code, I was making multiple calls with the API because I was calling the functions for creating the Person Group, adding People, adding images for the People, training the Person Group, and then identifying a Person. I believe that this is the main error.